# Connection refused when trying to send an event from keycloak

Tags: java, events, microservices, keycloak

I am trying to send an event from a keycloak to an endpoint to another microservice, when i try `SimpleHttp.doPost()` returns me connection refused. The endpoint itself works fine, so there must be something missing in the keycloak. Does anyone know why this is happening? Maybe I should add some configuration?

```
@JBossLog
public class HttpSenderEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

  protected static final String TARGET_URI = "http://localhost:1010/my-service/event";
  protected final KeycloakSession session;

  private Set<EventType> excludedEvents;

  private Set<OperationType> excludedAdminOperations;

  public HttpSenderEventListenerProvider(KeycloakSession session, Set<EventType> excludedEvents, Set<OperationType> excludedAdminOpearations) {
    this.session = session;
    this.excludedEvents = excludedEvents;
    this.excludedAdminOperations = excludedAdminOpearations;
  }

  @Override
  public void onEvent(Event event) {
    try {
      testConnection(event);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void onEvent(AdminEvent event, boolean b) {
    try {
      testConnectionAdmin(event);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    // close this instance of the event listener
  }

  private void testConnection(Event event) throws IOException{
    SimpleHttp request = SimpleHttp.doPost(TARGET_URI, session).json(event);
    SimpleHttp.Response response = request.asResponse();
    int status = response.getStatus();
  }

  private void testConnectionAdmin(AdminEvent event) throws IOException{
    SimpleHttp request = SimpleHttp.doPost(TARGET_URI, session).json(event);
    SimpleHttp.Response response = request.asResponse();
    int status = response.getStatus();
  }
}

public class EventListenerProviderFactoryImpl implements EventListenerProviderFactory {

    private Set<EventType> excludedEvents;
    private Set<OperationType> excludedAdminOperations;

    @Override
    public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return new HttpSenderEventListenerProvider(session, excludedEvents, excludedAdminOperations);
    }

{...}

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "sysout";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running your keycloak-server in a docker-container?